# Anti-Forgery Token issue: not on login or logout, but upon return to website from payment processor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have got the weirdest issue that I cannot seem to properly debug.

Current project:

- Asp.NET 4.7.2
- MVC 5

When a user logs in, they are able to log back out and back in without any issues. No token issues there. Timeout is for 60 minutes.

However, on this site there is a “cart” that users can put some very limited things into and pay for. The payment button moves them over to the payment processor (a hosted payment page), who then takes CC info and processes that payment. Once the payment is complete (or it fails), the user is shunted back to a specific page on the website, also within their account. The only thing this landing page does is look for a few GET values that the payment processor has added to the end of the URL, and records those values to the database (thereby recording the item in the cart as having been paid).

However, about one-third of people who get sent back from the payment processer - *after* a *successful* payment - are experiencing the

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.

error message.

So to be clear:

- The user goes to their cart, clicks on “Process Cart”.
- The user gets shunted over to the payment processor’s hosted payment page, leaving the current site entirely.
- The user makes payment on the payment processor’s hosted payment page.
- The payment processor processes the payment, and regardless of whether it fails or not, sends the user back to a specific landing page on the website that is behind the login and within their account.
- The error occurs at this point, when they are sent back to this landing page.

My code on this landing page is exceedingly simple:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Processed() {
  var responseCode = Request.QueryString["RESPONSECODE"];
  var orderId = Request.QueryString["ORDERID"];
  var customField = HelperExtensions.GetGuid(Request.QueryString["CUSTOMFIELD1"]);
  var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["AMOUNT"]);
  var cardNumber = Request.QueryString["CARDNUMBER"];
  var approvalCode = Request.QueryString["APPROVALCODE"];
  var uniqueRef = Request.QueryString["UNIQUEREF"];
  var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["DATETIME"]);
  if(string.Equals(responseCode, "A")) { // Transaction approved
    //Process these values and insert them into the DB to mark the cart as having been paid.
  }
  //Send *everyone* to the View, with appropriate messages served up by the view’s model depending on the responseCode.
  return View("Processed", new ProcessedViewModel(transactionId, responseCode, orderId, amount, cardNumber, approvalCode, uniqueRef, dateTime, additionalErrors));
}
```

I have already tried verifying this with a dummy account on the site, and manually generating a return URL that the landing page can “process”, but unless I am willing to rack up several thousand dollars in CC fees myself (these are membership fees, in the several hundred dollar range), I cannot work with a full round trip.

Please note that this issue is explicitly *not* showing up during login or logout. Or with a login immediately after a logout. It is *only* showing up after the user is sent back to the landing page from the payment processor.

Also please keep in mind: fully two thirds of users are not experiencing this bug. Only about one third of them are. So this appears to be a transient issue, and I have not yet tracked down the differences between the successful catches on the landing page and those catches that fail.

I have gone so far as to decorate *all* controllers with:

```
[NoCache]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

The first one being a no-cache attribute I found elsewhere on StackOverflow:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
  public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) {
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
  }
}
```

Despite this addition, the errors have not ceased (although there hasn’t been enough payments yet to determine if the ratio of token errors has changed).

Answer (score 0):

Anti-Forgery Tokens work with cookies, If the web browser is blocking the cookies it will cause this ERROR.

> "The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different
>   claims-based user than the current user."

Create an action that will log cookies that are blocked to compare to users with this issue.

Anti-Forgery Tokens are there to prevent against CSRF, assuming you have the customer leaving the site to Pay and returning to the users account without a cookie.

Create a custom Anti-Forgery Token so when browser cookies are disabled then token will be stored in session and also compare from session.

Take a look at this [site](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/securing_all_forms_using_antiforgerytoken).

Hope this helps